# Error build app ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to build for Android but without Android Studio. I did the necessary procedures, I downloaded sdkmanager, gradle but when I run the command `ionic cordova build android`. I get the following error:

> - What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

But I already installed sdkmanager, when I run the command sdkmanager --list I have the following output:

[image: output]

And I see that Android SDK tools is already installed in version 26.1.1, thanks any help.

Comment: can you please remove the platform android and add it again and try to build the project again.

Comment: Ok I'll try this

Comment: I'm getting the same error :(

Comment: In you screen shot I see `tools` but I don't see `android sdk build-tools` , you need to install that one too

Comment: you need to download build tools for specific version and set ANDROID_HOME too.

Comment: Ok! I did installation of build tools. I'll try again.

Comment: It worked. Thankful so much, you saved me RezaRahmati and Hiten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hiten and @RezaRahmati, I was able to solve my problem. My sdk folder was without the **build-tools** subdirectory. I ran the following command with sdkmanager: `sdkmanager "build-tools; 26.0.2"` and after I make the command `ionic cordova build android`. Worked perfectly.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to download build tools for specific android version and set ANDROID_HOME too. 
And then try to build again.